# How to access and change a java local variable with JVMTI and JNI

Tags: java, minecraft, jvmti

I am reading the JVMTI docs that give information on Local Variables. It said this:

jvmtiError
SetLocalFloat(jvmtiEnv* env,
jthread thread,
jint depth,
jint slot,
jfloat value)
How do I obtain the said method parameters?
Thanks for any help given.

I tried using this java agents library ByteBuddy, but I don't know how to change the variable, so I decided to use JVMTI.

(BTW this is for a minecraft cheat. The cheat is used only for educational purposes to gain more knowledge about the JVM's internals and the JNI API).

Comment: You can't do it with JNI.

Comment: How about JVMTI?